# «По-особенному». Отсутствие дефиса — это грубая ошибка?

Tags: орфография, наречия, дефис, типы-ошибок

Предположим, что в слове **по-особенному** отсутствует дефис.
Является ли это грубой ошибкой?

Answer (score 2):

В этом документе, приводимом со ссылкой на ЕГЭ, имеется отдельный перечень *негрубых орфографических* ошибок: http://lik-bez.com/publ/egeh/dokumenty_ege/tipy_oshibok/2-1-0-517

Самое близкое в нём - ошибки "*слитного и раздельного написания наречий, образованных от **существительных** с предлогами, правописание которых **не регулируется правилами***". В нашем случае наречия, образованого от полного *прилагательного*, правило **есть** (оно уже приведено в другом ответе). Поэтому в свете упомянутого выше документа соответствующую ошибку приходится признать *грубой*.

Comment: А, так это дела школьные?! Для преподавателей? Тогда, наверное, да...

Answer (score 0):

Слова в русском языке имеют **две формы написания:** слитную и дефисную. (Раздельно пишутся не слова, а словосочетания).

Слитная форма является основной, а **дефисная применяется в некоторых случаях, которые регламентируются правилами.**

Это важный раздел правописания, поэтому выбор неправильной формы  является **такой же орфографической ошибкой, как и выбор неправильной буквы.**

***По-особенному*** — дефисное написание наречия, что соответствует правилам Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=68#pp68

9. **Пишутся через дефис наречия с приставкой по-, образованные от полных форм прилагательных и от местоимений и оканчивающиеся на -ому/-ему, -ки, -ьи**: по-видимому; по-пустому; работать по-новому;  по-прежнему; пусть будет по-вашему; советовать по-дружески; говорить по-французски; хитрить по-лисьи, а также по-латыни.

Comment: Прошу убрать лишний мягкий знак в слове "приходитЬся" в последнем абзаце. Ну, не ожидал!

Comment: Спасибо, убрала всё. Вот не поверите, случайно написала. В любом случае, мне очень приятно знать, что Вы читаете мои ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Написание зависит от значения слова. Наречие требует дефиса **"по-особенному"**, прилагательное с предлогом нет: ***пошел по особенному пути**. Иные варианты - ошибка.

> Например, если в слове по-особенному отсутствует дефис, является ли
>   это не грубой ошибкой?

Грубыми могут быть ошибки орфоэпические, то есть связанные с произношением. Орфографические - нет.

Возможно, при изучении русского как иностранного преподаватели вводят такую градацию в зависимости от уровня подготовки студентов, но в учеьниках и пособиях по собственно русскому языку такого разделения орфографических ошибок я не встречал.

Может быть и иной подход, менее грубыми считаются те ошибки, которые допущены в "сложных" случаях, требующих более глубокого и детального анализа. Но и это понимание применимо только к ошибкам синтаксиса и - опосредовано - пунктуации.